# dynamic bar charts connect to databases

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database

I have a dynamic table based on db that if the user input a random number of proteins the table shows the name of the chromes, the number of associated proteins and the percentage of the number entered and the associated proteins;

I want to make a dynamic drop down menu that has two options the number of associated proteins and the percentage .Based on which is selected,I need to display a bar chart with the names the chromosomes on the x-axis and the selected metric on the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic
Visit  this link and pass the numeric value using ParseInt() function of JavaScript .